# Firebase data structure and filtering

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi everyone I want to ask. I have a data structure in firebase to later I want to filter the user based on gender so basically I want when user register based on gender I want to separate the chat room the male only meet for male and female only meet for female. I already make the structure and I don't know if this is a good structure, I want everyone opinions of this can I filter this in firebase?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions asking for opinions without providing very specific use case falls outside of the guidelines of this site. We don't know how the data will be used, what other kinds of queries you're going to use etc. The answer is yes, you can query by gender. However, you can not (as it stands) query by gender and age. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I keep that in mind, thank you ☺️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do some research , you can reach all answers for you question.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL(FIREBASE_URL).child("gender").
    queryOrderedByChild("male")
```

Comment: @user8907890 No - you do not need to make a *new* node for gender. You already have a gender node in your structure and can query by that node. If you need to do other queries then you may want to denormalize your data in other ways.